# Invalid parameter @tp_WokflowInstanceId passed to proc_UpdateListItem from SPRequest in updated database

Tags: upgrade, workflow, error

We're having a problem with workflows in a site collection. We see invalid parameter @tp_WokflowInstanceId passed to proc_UpdateListItem from SPRequest in V2V upgrated database when a SPListItem.Update() or SPListItem.SystemUpdate() are invoked. On the same server we created a new site collection with a separate database and there SPRequest behaves correctly.

The calls seen in SQL Server Profiler are as follows:

```
--FAILING UPGRADED DB, Contains a record in dbo.Versions referencing a 12.0... version number
exec sp_executesql N'BEGIN TRAN;DECLARE @@iRet INT,@DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@S uniqueidentifier,@@Level tinyint,@@DocUIVersion int,@ExtraItemSize bigint;SET @@iRet = 0;SET @@S=@wssp0;SET @@Level=@wssp1;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512; SELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateListItem @SiteId=@wssp2,@WebId=@wssp3,@ListId=@wssp4,@ItemId=@wssp5,@RowOrdinal=@wssp6,@OnRestore=@wssp7,@ReturnRowset=1,@UseNvarchar1ItemName=@wssp8,@ItemDirName=@DN OUTPUT,@ItemLeafName=@LN OUTPUT,@UserId=@wssp9,@TimeNow=@wssp10,@PreserveVersion=@wssp11,@IsMeetingsList=@wssp12,@IsIssueList=@wssp13,@IsNotUserDisplayed=@wssp14,@SystemUpdate=@wssp15,@ChangeLevel=@wssp16,@CheckinItem=@wssp17,@NeedClone=@wssp18,@MajorVersionsLimit=@wssp19,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=@wssp20,@NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion OUTPUT,@Level=@@Level OUTPUT,@IsDocLib=0, @tp_Version=@wssp21,@CheckSchemaVersion=@wssp22, @tp_ContentTypeId = @wssp23, @nvarchar1 = @wssp24, @nvarchar3 = @wssp25, @nvarchar4 = @wssp26, @float1 = @wssp27 , @int2 = @wssp28, @ntext2 = @wssp29, @datetime1 = @wssp30, @datetime2 = @wssp31, @tp_Modified = @wssp32, @tp_WorkflowInstanceID = @wssp33, @tp_Author = @wssp34, @tp_WorkflowVersion = @wssp35, @tp_Created = @wssp36, @tp_Editor = @wssp37, @tp_ModerationStatus = @wssp38, @tp_ItemOrder = @wssp39 , @nvarchar5 = @wssp40, @nvarchar6 = @wssp41, @nvarchar10 = @wssp42, @int4 = @wssp43, @ntext4 = @wssp44, @bit1 = @wssp45, @bit2 = @wssp46, @bit3 = @wssp47, @uniqueidentifier1 = @wssp48, @int5 = @wssp49, @Size=@wssp50, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@NeedsAuthorRestriction=@wssp51,@NeedsDraftOwnerRestriction=@wssp52,@BumpLastDelete=@wssp53,@CreateItemVersion=@wssp54,@ItemName=@wssp55, @eventData=@wssp56, @acl=@wssp57,@IsFirstRow=@wssp58; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END 
EXEC @@iRet = proc_RemoveJunctions  @SiteId = @wssp59, @DirName = @DN, @LeafName = @LN, @FieldId = @wssp60, @Level = @@Level; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END 
EXEC @@iRet = proc_SecUpdateUserActiveStatus @wssp61, @wssp62; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END 
EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level, @wssp63; EXEC @@iRet = proc_EnsureTranLockNotRequired @wssp64, @wssp65, @wssp66;;IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END; EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @@S,1; COMMIT TRAN; '
--WORKING FRESH DB, no 12.0... references in dbo.Versions
exec sp_executesql N'BEGIN TRAN;DECLARE @@iRet INT,@DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@S uniqueidentifier,@@Level tinyint,@@DocUIVersion int,@ExtraItemSize bigint;SET @@iRet = 0;SET @@S=@wssp0;SET @@Level=@wssp1;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512; SELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_UpdateListItem @SiteId=@wssp2,@WebId=@wssp3,@ListId=@wssp4,@ItemId=@wssp5,@RowOrdinal=@wssp6,@OnRestore=@wssp7,@ReturnRowset=1,@UseNvarchar1ItemName=@wssp8,@ItemDirName=@DN OUTPUT,@ItemLeafName=@LN OUTPUT,@UserId=@wssp9,@TimeNow=@wssp10,@PreserveVersion=@wssp11,@IsMeetingsList=@wssp12,@IsIssueList=@wssp13,@IsNotUserDisplayed=@wssp14,@SystemUpdate=@wssp15,@ChangeLevel=@wssp16,@CheckinItem=@wssp17,@NeedClone=@wssp18,@MajorVersionsLimit=@wssp19,@MajorMinorVersionsLimit=@wssp20,@NewUIVersion = @@DocUIVersion OUTPUT,@Level=@@Level OUTPUT,@IsDocLib=0, @tp_Version=@wssp21,@CheckSchemaVersion=@wssp22, @tp_ContentTypeId = @wssp23, @nvarchar16 = @wssp24, @tp_Modified = @wssp25, @tp_WorkflowVersion = @wssp26, @tp_ModerationStatus = @wssp27, @tp_ItemOrder = @wssp28 , @nvarchar3 = @wssp29, @nvarchar4 = @wssp30, @float1 = @wssp31 , @int2 = @wssp32, @ntext2 = @wssp33, @datetime1 = @wssp34, @datetime2 = @wssp35, @nvarchar5 = @wssp36, @nvarchar6 = @wssp37, @nvarchar10 = @wssp38, @int4 = @wssp39, @ntext4 = @wssp40, @bit1 = @wssp41, @bit2 = @wssp42, @bit3 = @wssp43, @uniqueidentifier1 = @wssp44, @int5 = @wssp45, @nvarchar12 = @wssp46, @bit4 = @wssp47, @Size=@wssp48, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@NeedsAuthorRestriction=@wssp49,@NeedsDraftOwnerRestriction=@wssp50,@BumpLastDelete=@wssp51,@CreateItemVersion=@wssp52,@ItemName=@wssp53, @eventData=@wssp54, @acl=@wssp55,@IsFirstRow=@wssp56; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END  EXEC @@iRet = proc_EnsureTranLockNotRequired @wssp57, @wssp58, @wssp59;;IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END; EXEC proc_UpdateDiskUsed @@S,1; COMMIT TRAN;'
```

I'm not sure what [proc_GetVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd358416%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx) should return as both v12 and v14 have the same zero guids.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Moving the site collection to a new
database within the Web application
did not resolve the issue. I still get

> [COMException (0x80131904):
>
> 0x80131904]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean
>   bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String&
>   pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean
>   bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object&
>   pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pRestrictInsertCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqueFieldCallback) +0
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean
>   bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String&
>   pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean
>   bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object&
>   pvarAttachmentContents, Object&
>   pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut,
>   Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pListDataValidationCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pRestrictInsertCallback,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pUniqueFieldCallback) +406

and

> Unknown exception SQL 8145
>   @tp_WorkflowInstanceID is not a parameter for procedure proc_UpdateListItem.

Comment: Todd Klindt suggested doing Move-SPSite to the new database. Interesting idea.

Comment: That didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this issue has not been resolved, here's what we resorted to: create the Content Database from scratch. This was acceptable for our issue arose in a test environment.

Anyway, I think this could possibly also arise in a pre-production upgrade farm, so future investigation of such upgrade issues is more than welcome. Wish I had some horsepower and time to get back to troubleshooting this one. Always sad to leave unresolved issues behind.